# Check information double table

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

how could I do it to check if in the table exists Character name, Table> characters> Character before proceeding with registration to Structure
characters old

Comment: I want it to check if someone already exists using the same name, it does not let register in the table

Comment: Please show us your model code so we can help you out

Comment: Okay my modal is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check name in the DB before inserting the new record

```
$data = array(
    "id_username" => $this->session->id_account,
    "name_character" => $nome,
    "birthdate" => $data,
    "origin" => $origem,
    "gender" => $sexo,
    "pergunta1" => $pergunta3,
    "pergunta2" => $pergunta4,
    "history" => $history
);
$if_exists = $this->usuarios_model->check_user($data['name_character']);

//Here apply condition to check if user is exists or not
if($if_exists > 0){
    //Already Exists
}else{
    $this->usuarios_model->criarPersonagem($data); //New registration
}
```

**Model**

```
public function check_user($name_character){

    //Here, get the number if rows with the new user name
    return $this->db->get_where('characters', ['Character' => $name_character])->num_rows();
}
```

Comment: Message: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: @PedroHB sorry for late reply. Fixed

Comment: @PedroHB you are missing `curly bracket` somewhere in the file.

Comment: error >   Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'name_character' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM `characters` WHERE `name_character` = 'pedro_henrique'

Comment: According to your question, your column name is `name_character`. Make sure the correct name here `['name_character' => $name_character]`

Comment: Table Characters > Character

Comment: `Character` is the column name?

Comment: Yeah, Table characters, column name is Character

Comment: @PedroHB fixed. Try and let me know

Comment: yeah tanks, haamm error > Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::num_row()

Comment: @PedroHB it's `num_rows()` not `num_row()`

Comment: Okay. I think the issue is resolved. Now you need to redirect to view in `if()` and `else` statement.

Comment: Nicee brow, tks

Comment: Brow, i upload my code in hospedagem, is error >> Message: syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: @PedroHB may be there is PHP version issue. Try this `return $this->db->get_where('characters', array('Character' => $name_character))->num_rows();`

Comment: friend, can you help me make a code in which it verifies if the user already has a characters created in the table> character> Username, if one already exists, he did not let him create more?

Comment: ex:  if ($this->db->get_where('characters', array('Username, $nome))->num_rows() > 0) { // redirect to error page }

Answer (score 0):

**controller:**

```
$flag = $this->usuarios_model->criarPersonagem($data);
if($flag == 1){
    redirect("painel/sucesso"); // lembrar de criar a mensagem sucesso!
}else{
    redirect("painel/fracasso"); // lembrar de criar a mensagem fracasso!
}
```

**Model:**

```
function criarPersonagem($data){
      $query = $this->db->get_where('characters',array('name_character'=>$data['name_character']));
      if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
         return 0;
      }else{
         //register code
         return 1;
      }
}
```